# file upload ajax in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I create a file upload in laravel in normal action and in normal action file uploaded successfully  but when i use ajax to upload file that is not successfully.

I use blade template and this is my form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'send-file','files'=>true, 'method' => 'post')) }} 
{{ Form::label('file', 'File' ,array()) }}
{{ Form::file('img', array('id' => 'iefile') ) }}
{{ Form::submit('send') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
<div id="progress">
        progress
        </div>
```

And this is my jquery code :

```
 $('form').submit(function(e) { // capture submit
        e.preventDefault();
        var fd = new FormData(this); // XXX: Neex AJAX2

        // You could show a loading image for example...

        $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('action'),
          xhr: function() { // custom xhr (is the best)

               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
               var total = 0;

               // Get the total size of files
               $.each(document.getElementById('iefile').files, function(i, file) {
                      total += file.size;
               });

               // Called when upload progress changes. xhr2
               xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                      // show progress like example
                      var loaded = (evt.loaded / total).toFixed(2)*100; // percent

                      $('#progress').text('Uploading... ' + loaded + '%' );
               }, false);

               return xhr;
          },
          type: 'post',
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          data: fd,
          success: function(data) {
               // do something...
               alert('uploaded');
          }
        });
    });
```

And this is my Rout in Routs.php

```
Route::any('send-file', function()
{
    $file = Input::file('img');
     $destinationPath = dirname(__DIR__).'/uploads';
    // If the uploads fail due to file system, you can try doing public_path().'/uploads' 
    //$filename = str_random(12);
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    if (Input::hasFile('img'))
    {
            $upload_success = $file ->move($destinationPath , $filename);
    }

    echo $destinationPath ;

});
```

But when i select a file and click on submit button progress section change and display percent of uploaded file. But at end of file upload a error display in chrome console .and this error display in app/storage/logs/laravel.log :

```
[2015-01-08 05:10:01] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object' in /var/www/usb/app/routes.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Comment: If you `dd($file = Input::file('img'))` it's null?

Comment: after ask this question i find out the above code work fine for small file.and do not work for big file.can you tell me how i can change Upload-max-filesize ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size